# Python referencing qt objects from other classes

Tags: python, qt

I am new to python and QT and I am trying to integrate some qt into python. I have a GUI and a class in there like this where I set up a checkbox

```
class createTestWidget: 
...

def setup(self):  
... 
self.runTestCheckBox = qt.QCheckBox("Run the Test")
self.layout.addWidget(self.runTestCheckBox) ....
```

Now I have another class (class testLogic:) which is dependent on the state of this checkbox. If it is checked, I will run the test, if not, I won't. I am not sure how to check the state. I tried something like this: self.runTestCheckBox.checkStateSet() but obviously it gives me an error saying that testLogic does not have an attribute runTestCheckBox. I would appreciate it you can point out how I can look at the state of the checkbox.

Comment: pass the value of runTestCheckBox.checked() to an attribute in testLogic?

Comment: Yea I guess that works instead of figuring out how to get a handle to the checkbox... Thanks!